# Javafx TableCell When start editing, show old value

Tags: javafx, datepicker, tableview, tablecell, javafx-tableview

I have extended the `TableCell` class to render a date picker. Its graphic is a `javafx.scene.control.DatePicker`. I have had to do some `onKeyPressed` handling to handle tab, enter, and escape, and some other customizations to try to get this `TableCell` acting in a sane way. Now, when I first select the cell which already contains a value, the `DatePicker` shows up, but it's blank. It looks like `startEdit` is being called, but that doesn't provide a value to put into the `DatePicker`. (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableCell.html)

How do I make the old value of the cell show up in the `DatePicker` when it first shows up?

Comment: Assuming the column type is `LocalDate`, can't you just do `datePicker.setValue(getItem())` in `startEdit()`?

Comment: @James_D Perfect, thanks. I was looking for `getValue`, and missed `getItem`. Put it as an answer, and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the column type is `LocalDate`, just call

```
datePicker.setValue(getItem());
```

in the `startEdit()` method.